# Chi-squared distribution variable spectral analysis

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density

I an interested in spectral analysis of a random signal.

Assume the signal $n(t)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ is followed by the white Gaussian noise with zero mean and $\sigma^2$ variance.

The test signal is $z(t)=n^2(t)$.

Obviously, $z(t)$ is the Chi-squared distribution with 1 degree of freedom.

The histogram of $z(t)$ with $\sigma^2=1$.

[image: waveform of z(t)]

The Normalized FFT spectrum of $z(t)$ is shown following:

[image: FFT spectrum]

The spectrum has an impulse at the zero frequency and a flat platform over the other frequencies. Obviously, the impulse is caused by the DC component in $z(t)$ with $E(z)=\sigma^2$.

My question is: is there any possible mathematical description of $z(t)$?

Comment: In what sense? You mean an alternative expression for $z(t)$? If yes, what is $z$ supposed to be expressed as a function of in that case?

Comment: Slides 5-7 in http://isl.stanford.edu/~abbas/ee278/lect07.pdf